# Dynamic Web Query

Tags: excel, vba

Go easy on me as I am new at this. I have created a couple of macros that extract search results from:Sec full text search: http://searchwww.sec.gov/EDGARFSClient/jsp/EDGAR_MainAccess.jsp

Now that my data is all cleaned up and set in different columns, I need to create a query based off of the results. In column B I have a list of company names, I would like to reference each cell in column "B", and query market watch at http://www.marketwatch.com/tools/quotes/lookup.asp?siteID=mktw&Lookup=options+media&Country=us&Type=All for the ticker symbol related to the company name. That would help me out, as eventually I will want to perform multiple queries pulling information about share structure, revenues ect. I would greatly appreciate any time in answering this question.

Comment: Surely you can modify your first macros to perform the requests, you just need to loop over the results from the first. Edit your post to include your macros and maybe we can help further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code.

```
Sub website()

    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim htmTable As HTMLTable

    Set doc = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/BAC"
        .send
        Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4
        doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        .abort
    End With

    Set htmTable = doc.getElementsByClassName("companyname")(0)

    If Not htmTable Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox htmTable.innerText
    End If

     Set htmTable = doc.getElementsByClassName("lastprice")(0)

    If Not htmTable Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox htmTable.innerText
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Santosh, I know I am going to feel silly for asking this but how do I set the url parameters on that? Im learned a little of the ?= format, but that url I am not so sure. The results that I am getting at the moment are of course Bank of Americas

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, if anyone has the same question I used the url: http://www.marketwatch.com/tools/quotes/lookup.asp?lookup=             Thanks Again, I will have to tweak it to fit my needs but it is definitely what I was looking for

Comment: @RolandSmith Can you vote if you found the answer to be helpful.

Comment: I have no problem with that, as this answer was very helpful. The problem lies in the fact that I do not have enough reputation points to vote up (15 min are required). I am assuming this is to avoid automated voting processes, unfortunately it also effects new users